# D3: Populate Table from Dict when Line Selected

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js

I have a nested dictionary that I created for my d3 line chart. I'm trying to populate a table with the dictionary data when I mouseover certain lines in the chart. So far I have been able to populate the `Site` column when I mouseover the lines.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Site</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Priority</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = "id1"></td>
    <td id = "id2"></td>
    <td id = "id3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function mouseover(d) {
    var info = {"A" : {"model":"100", "priority":"Important"},
                "B" : {"model":"60", "priority":"Not Important"},
                "C" : {"model":"80", "priority":"Important"},
                "D" : {"model":"80", "priority":"Not Important"},
                "E" : {"model":"60", "priority":"Important"}
           }
    d3.select("#id1").text(d.data.site);   // works

}
```

The expected **output** in the table would look like the following when the mouse hovers over Line `"B"`:

```
Site   Model     Priority
 B      60     Not Important
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I apologize for my post...

In case anyone is wondering how to do this:

```
function mouseover(d) {
    var info = {"A" : {"model":"100", "priority":"Important"},
                "B" : {"model":"60", "priority":"Not Important"},
                "C" : {"model":"80", "priority":"Important"},
                "D" : {"model":"80", "priority":"Not Important"},
                "E" : {"model":"60", "priority":"Important"}
           }
    d3.select("#id1").text(d.data.site);
    d3.select("#id2").text(info[d.data.site]["model"]);
    d3.select("#id3").text(info[d.data.site]["priority"]);
}
```